# MySQL Queries and 2 separate tables

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables in a MySQL database, one for "Users" and the other for "Orders", where each entry in Orders is an order placed by a User (Some users can have multiple orders, while some might not have any).  I am working on reporting queries and one of the reports I want is a list of Users that have never placed any orders.  I am still a bit of a beginner when it comes to MySQL queries, so I am not sure how to do this one.  The query will be placed via PHP if that makes any difference.

Here are my columns in each table (simplified):

Users:

```
ID
Name
```

Orders:

```
OrderID
OrderName
CustomerID      (corresponds to User.ID that placed the order)
```

Any help here would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` on Orders and check whether OrderId is null:

```
SELECT U.*
FROM
 Users U
 LEFT JOIN Orders O ON(U.ID = O.CustomerID)
WHERE
 O.OrderId IS NULL
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3a9d/2)

Comment: this will be faster on large data amount in DB

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM users 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT customerID FROM Orders)
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you'are looking for orders that are not made by that user

```
Select * from Orders where CustomerID = 5 //5 is the id of the custumer
```

If you are doing a search by name

```
Select * from Orders LEFT JOIN Users on Users.ID Where Users.name ='Mark'
```

If no results, it mean that customer never ordered anything

Comment: You don't need a LEFT JOIN since you're searching by Users.name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT U.*
FROM   Orders a
           RIGHT JOIN Users b 
               ON b.ID = a.CustomerID
WHERE  a.OrderId IS NULL
```